# Вычисление размера массива(члена класса) на этапе компиляции

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

Нужно написать **constexpr** конструктор:

```
template<typename T, uint64_t Mask>
class SparseArray 
{
  private:
  T values[/*Посчитать размер прореженного массива*/];
}
```

Чтобы проверка была успешно пройдена:

```
int main() 
{
  SparseArray < float, 3 > array0(1.0f, 2.0f);
  static_assert(sizeof(array0) == sizeof(float) * 2, "Invalid array size");
}
```

//======================================

На данный момент смог пробросить аргументы:

```
template<typename... Args>
constexpr SparseArray(Args&&... args) : values{args...}
{ }
```

Т.е. отсюда можно взять их количество с помощью *sizeof...(Args)*.

Отдельно получилось задавать размер внутреннего массива таким образом:

```
  static constexpr int calcSize()
  {
    return Mask - 1;
  }

  T values[calcSize()];
```

Сочетать оба подхода - вычисление количества аргументов и задание размера массива не получается.

Comment: Вы решаете такую же задачу? http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread2216255.html если да, то размер - это количество единичных бит в передаваемом вторым параметре числе. Считается в compile-time без проблем. Могу оформить ответ с пояснениями, если задача такая же.

Comment: @Croessmah да, точно. та же задача. Я пока сам хочу пробраться) Спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: тогда вот еще, там подробнее объяснил суть mask в этой задаче. http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread2219945.html#post12263994

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так сделать не выйдет просто потому, что следующая конструкция должна всегда давать какой-то результат: `sizeof(SparseArray<...>)`. Как может давать результат такая конструкция, если Вы хотите вычислять размер массива исходя из параметров конструктора? Не выйдет. Конструктор это функция класса и из него нельзя вычислить аргументы шаблона для класса, т.е. всё, что относится к «статической» части класса, вычислить в конструкторе невозможно.

Есть одна лазейка, появившаяся в C++17, которая называется deduction guides (писал о них [тут](http://scrutator.me/post/2017/08/11/cpp17_lang_features_p1.aspx#template_args_deduction)). Она как раз позволяет вычислить аргументы шаблона для класса на основании того, как создаётся объект . Но тогда запрещено явно указывать аргументы при создании объекта. Т.е. если у Вас есть зависимость между `Mask` и размером массива, то можно сделать так:

```
template<typename T, uint64_t Mask, uint64_t Size = Mask - 1>
class SparseArray
{
public:
    template<typename... U>
    constexpr SparseArray(U... args): values{args...}
    { }
private:
    T values[Size];
};

template<typename T, typename... U>
SparseArray(T arg, U... tail) -> SparseArray<T, sizeof...(U) + 2>;
```

Тогда мы можем использовать полученный класс вот так:

```
int main()
{
    SparseArray array0{1.0f, 2.0f};
    static_assert(sizeof(array0) == sizeof(float) * 2, "Invalid array size");
}
```

Если же такое не подходит, то можно воспользоваться свободной функцией (либо же статической) и создавать Ваш объект через неё:

```
template<typename T, uint64_t Mask, typename... Us>
auto createSparseArray(T arg, Us... tail)
{
    return SparseArray<T, Mask, sizeof...(Us) + 1>(arg, tail...);
}
```

Тогда совершенно не важно, есть ли зависимость между `Mask` и размером массива, или нет.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Насчет С++17 тоже успел попробовать и дошел как раз до: **Но тогда запрещено явно указывать аргументы при создании объекта**. В примере не понял что за _+ 2_

Comment: @ВладимирН, +1 от того, что мы разделили все аргументы на arg и tail, т.е. +1 за arg. Ещё +1 из-за того, что у Вас в коде Mask == array_size + 1

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T, uint64_t Mask>
class SparseArray 
{
  constexpr size_t popcount (size_t value) {
    return value != 0 ? (value & 0b1) + popcount(value >> 1) : 0;
  }
  private:
  T values[popcount(Mask)];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Получается, здесь идет подсчет количества бит в _Mask_. Очень интересно!